# Why does mapping a function with bind no longer work with ee.List.sequence

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Since last week, mapping a function of more than one arguments over result from ee.List.sequence using 'bind' no longer works although it can be mapped over a regular list.  Why?  e.g.

// simple function

```
var add_x = function(n, x) {
  return n + x;
}
```

**// This command returns expected result

```
print([1,2,3,4,5].map(add_x.bind(null,10)));

[11,12,13,14,15]
```

**// This command results in an error

```
print(ee.List.sequence(1,5,1).map(add_x.bind(null,10)));

List (Error)
List.map: A mapped algorithm must take one argument.
```

Comment: What do "no longer work" and "this throws error" mean? Make sure to read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit this question to include relevant error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me. (I've reported it.) Until it's fixed, you can replace `bind` with a handwritten version for `add_x` in particular:

```js
var add_x = function(n, x) {
  return ee.Number(n).add(x);
}

var bind_add_x = function(n) {
  return function (x) {
    return add_x(n, x);
  }
}

print(ee.List.sequence(1,5,1).map(bind_add_x(10)));
```

Comment: The proposal to use currying solves the problem but does not address the underlying issue of an error when using 'bind' for functions mapped over ee.List.sequence but no error when mapped over a ee.List as both return as ee.List() as input to the mapped function.

Comment: @RichardFernandes Yes, this is only a workaround for the bug.